# tikz-uml component box not include shift element

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I try to connect two class with a help point (M) but the component do not cover that point, so my connection line is outside of the component box.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background,foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlpackage}{DecoratorPattern}
\umlclass[]{Shape}{}{+void draw()}
\umlclass[below=1cm of Shape]{Rectangle}{}{+draw()}
\umlclass[left=1cm of Rectangle]{Circle}{}{+draw()}
\umlclass[right=1cm of Rectangle]{ShapeDecorator}{}{+draw()\\+void setRedBorder()}
\umlclass[below=1cm of ShapeDecorator]{RedShapeDecorator}{}{+draw()\\+void setRedBorder()}
\umlinherit[geometry=|-|]{Circle}{Shape}
\umlinherit[geometry=|-|]{Rectangle}{Shape}
\umlinherit[geometry=|-|]{ShapeDecorator}{Shape}
\umlinherit[geometry=|-|]{RedShapeDecorator}{ShapeDecorator}
\coordinate (M) at ([xshift=1cm]ShapeDecorator.east |- Shape);
\umlaggreg[geometry=-|]{ShapeDecorator}{M};
\umlassoc[geometry=--]{M}{Shape};
\end{umlpackage}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I do not use the help point, the connection position will be intersect with other connection line.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the coordinate you can use

```
\umlemptyclass[right=1cm of ShapeDecorator,coordinate,opacity=0]{M}
```

The `coordinate` option makes it a `\coordinate` instead of a normal `node`, and `opacity=0` makes it invisible. You then need to slightly change how you draw the lines as well, see comments in code.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background,foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlpackage}{DecoratorPattern}
\umlclass[]{Shape}{}{+void draw()}
\umlclass[below=1cm of Shape]{Rectangle}{}{+draw()}
\umlclass[left=1cm of Rectangle]{Circle}{}{+draw()}
\umlclass[right=1cm of Rectangle]{ShapeDecorator}{}{+draw()\\+void setRedBorder()}
\umlclass[below=1cm of ShapeDecorator]{RedShapeDecorator}{}{+draw()\\+void setRedBorder()}
\umlinherit[geometry=|-|]{Circle}{Shape}
\umlinherit[geometry=|-|]{Rectangle}{Shape}
\umlinherit[geometry=|-|]{ShapeDecorator}{Shape}
\umlinherit[geometry=|-|]{RedShapeDecorator}{ShapeDecorator}

\umlemptyclass[right=1cm of ShapeDecorator,coordinate,opacity=0,draw=none]{M}

\umlaggreg[geometry=--]{ShapeDecorator}{M} % use -- here
\umlassoc[geometry=|-]{M}{Shape} % and |- here
\end{umlpackage}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```